# How can I resize VirtualBox .vdi disk?

Tags: virtualbox

Is it possible to resize a disk image in VirtualBox 6 on Mac OS X?

Comment: What research have you done that leaves you with no viable solutions?

Comment: @IconDaemon I clicked everywhere within the UI only to not find any option to resize the solution.  I then found the solution through a blog, hence answering my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the following could be used in VirtualBox 6.0.12, as per some blog articles:

`/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxManage modifymedium disk ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/NetBSD-8.1-amd64/NetBSD-8.1-amd64.vdi --resize 10240`

It changes the size of the disk to about 10GB (from the original 5GB).

For some reason, there's no GUI to do this within the main app itself.

Comment: Links to the blog articles would be good.

Comment: @Mark why?  What's the missing from the answer?  The blogs weren't even Mac-related.

Comment: Because you are quoting from them - you should say which ones for attribution. Alkso we can see what assumptions they made. Random blogs are not necessarily reliable - which is why we have voting here

Comment: @Mark what is there to quote?  The only thing being quoted is `VBoxManage modifymedium`, that's hardly enough letters to cite any given blog for attribution.